# Как сохранить картинку в базу данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Пишу сайт и столкнулся с проблемой как сохранить изображения в базу данных. Пересмотрел кучу видео но так и не понял как это сделать с веб приложениям, так как везде одни примеры на виндовс формах. Суть такова что я получаю из веб формы с страницы изображения используя `<input type="file">`но не понимаю как мне это кодировать в Base64 чтобы записать в базу данных MongoDB

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZkoeNNjpmA

Comment: как по мне лучше в бд не картинки хранить, а ссылки на них, а сами картинки на каком-нибудь сервисе в облаке

Comment: Convert.ToBase64String. Но лучше лить картинку на какой-нибудь amazon/azure, а не хранить в базе.

Answer (score 0):

В бд хранишь путь к фото, очень удобно будет разделять фотки в папке img по древовидной системе. Потом просто кидаешь в представление путь к фото, и кидаешь его в src тега изображения.